# c program code does not stop looping without printing a new line

Tags: c

I have some c code that is meant to list all the permutations of an ordered int array and then use each permutation (for the moment I am just printing them) but I had noticed that although the function works as intended, when ever I remove the printf("\n"); in the main, the program works, but does not stop. With it, it works fine. The code is below. Can anyone help me to understand what is going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 4

int nextPermutation (int array[], int arraySize);

int main()
{
    int *array = calloc(ARRAYSIZE,sizeof(int)),i;

    for(i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        array[i]=i+1;
    }

    while(nextPermutation(array,ARRAYSIZE))
    {

        for(i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ",array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}

int nextPermutation(int array[], int arraySize)
{

    int maxElement=arraySize,i,maxElementIndex,inDecOrder;

    //check to see if the array is in descending order
    for(i=0; i<arraySize-1; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]<array[i+1])
        {
            inDecOrder = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    //if the array is in descending order then return 0
    if(inDecOrder)return 0;
    //find the index of the max element.
    for(i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]==maxElement)
        {
            maxElementIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(maxElementIndex!=0)
    {
        //if the max element is not in the first index then move it left and get next permutation
        array[i]=array[i-1];
        array[i-1]=maxElement;
        return 1;

    }
    else
    {
        //if the max index is in the first index then create an array without the max index
        int *newArray = calloc(arraySize-1,sizeof(int));

        //copy the elements from the first array into the new array with out the max element and get next permutation
        for(i=1; i<arraySize; i++)
        {
            newArray[i-1]=array[i];
        }
        nextPermutation(newArray,arraySize-1);
        for(i=0; i<arraySize-1; i++)
        {
            array[i]=newArray[i];
        }
        array[arraySize-1]=maxElement;
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: `inDecOrder` initialize like `int inDecOrder = 1;`

Comment: [Enable your compiler warnings and treat them as errors.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddaf7de1df80c3fa).

Comment: @WhozCraig, should I enable all the compiler warnings in the settings?

Comment: At least the ones I showed in the linked example, certainly. Toolchains vary in how to do it, but always do it. Warnings are almost always flags that your program has at least a logic error. They should be *fixed*; not ignored.

Comment: Doing what @BLUEPIXY had told me to had fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The stdio library buffers output and only writes it out for real when it either encounter a newline character ('\n') in the output stream or when you explicitely call the fflush() function.